# DXF format for QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dxf

I am trying to import some DWG files into QGIS.  I am using ODA to convert the DWG files to DXF and then want to use the Dxf2Shp converter plugin in QGIS.

The ODA converter has many options for the format of the DXF files it will output various options of ASCII or BINARY DXF file e.g. 2003 ASCI DXF, 2010 Binary DXF, R9 ASCII DXF plus more in similar styles

Which of the DWG file types will the Dxf2Shp plugin use best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you best bet is to stick with 2003 ASCI DXF. This is the format that I have always used and it works fine.

Also depending on your needs you might not need the Dxf2Shp plugin as QGIS (using OGR) can open .dxf file directly via the Add Vector Layer button.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I have had limited results using 2003 ASCI DXF format but I think this more to do with the original files than anything else. I suspect that the conversion of the original DWG files to DXF has given them some fatal errors as when trying to open the dxf file directly in QGIS as you suggest I get a "file.dxf is not a valid or recognized data source" message.

Comment: OK, went back to the beginning and repeated the conversion from .dwg to .dxf using ODA and the 2013 ASCII DXF format. Then added layer using Nathan's suggestion above which worked. It appears there is a fundamental problem to the way the original 'survey' data was collected and drawn.

Comment: DXF is a horrible format so sometimes you just have to play around until you find the right match.